# Passing the value from a form_for to another user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to add a feature in my app that allows a logged in user (first user) to go to another users page (second user) and send them a message. I want this message to be saved to a variable associated with the second user. Currently, when the first user sends the message it is being saved within their own user model instead of being passed to the second user. Please see my code below:

Controller

```
    def create
  @feedback = current_user.feedbacks.create(feedback_params)
  #@sender = @feedback.sender
  @receiver = @feedback.receiver
  if @feedback.save!
     flash[:success] = "Feedback sent!"
     redirect_to root_url
  else 
     render 'new'
  end
 end 

 def new
  @feedback = Feedback.new
  @feedback_receiver= @feedback.receiver 
 end 

 def view
 end 

 def destroy
 end 

 def index
 end 

 private




      def feedback_params
       params.require(:feedback).permit(:content, :receiver_id, :user_id)
      end 
    end
```

Form_for

```
     <% provide(:title, "Give feedback") %>
<h1> Give feedback </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class= "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "How can I improve myself?", object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:receiver_id, @feedback.receiver_id) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the line mentioned below as quoted from post:

> Currently, when the first user sends the message it is being saved
>   within their own user model instead of being passed to the second
>   user.

Seems like you want to store the messages corresponding to reciever(second user) as well.

In such a case modify your feedbacks table to have a sender_id as well. Currently you are only having only user_id (assuming based on the line current_user.feedbacks.build)

Thus there will be two associations in user.rb to feedbacks.

```
 has_many :feebacks_sent, class_name: "Feedback", foreign_key: :sender_id
 has_many :feedbacks_recieved, class_name: "Feedback", foreign_key: :reciever_id
```

So, now when first_user sends messages to second_user then feedbacks table will have following entries apart from the one you need as per application requirement:

```
reciever_id: "One to which the message is being sent"
sender_id: "One who is sending the message"
message: "Text which is being sent"
```

Also modify the feedback params as now you be needing to permit as the receiver_id

```
def feedback_params
 params.require(:feedback).permit(:content,:receiver_id)
end
```

Hope it answers the question.

Comment: I'm following your logic however do you know how I should modify the "def create" in the Feedbacks controller in order to match this change in the model?

Comment: also, do I need to update my form? I am receiving form errors that say "User can't be blank". @Rohan

Comment: I believe this issue is related to the "User" not being assigned to the feedback receiver....do you know how I would accomplish this @Rohan

Comment: As per the form you are getting user_id which I belive is not the current user
so modify the feedback params where you will be passing in the reciever_id as shared in the answer

Comment: If not then you need to get the second user_id (reciver_id) passed to the create method as well to permit the same in the database

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I really appreciate it. I have updated my original post to reflect the change in code. The issue I am having now is that the message (feedback) is not being passed to the receiver within the form. If I use an f.collection_select in my form this will correct the issue, however I want to be able to pass it on automatically, without the f.collection_select. Thoughts? @Rohan

Comment: Just to clarify, my overall goal is to pass this message over to the receiver in the database so the receiver will be able to view it on their User page @Rohan

Comment: so for that you will be needing another field to check if the receiver has viewed the message or not.which can be managed by having a boolean field in the feedback table indicating whether the receiver has viewed the message or not

Comment: Yes I understand that however do you know how to resolve the issue with the form? How can I pass the message to the message receiver automatically? @Rohan

Comment: How can a message be passed on to the reciever from the form??..The flow must be that from the form the sender sends the message, message saves in database and then when the second user logs in he will see the message in his show page

Comment: You will be needing a show page for showing the messages corresponding to second user which has been sent by users other than second user.

Comment: So I guess what I trying to say is....how will I save the message to the receiver? As my original post said, my current framework is only saving the message to the sender.

Comment: While saving sender_id, message and receiver_id in feedbacks table, so it will saving corresponding to sender and receiver as well and then you can use custom association to fetch received_messages for a particular user

Comment: please confirm that sender_id and receiver_id is storing in feedbacks table?

Comment: No, that is the main issue here. Sender_id and receiver_id are being saved to the same user (the sender). That’s why I was asking about how to use the form to assign the receiver as well. @Rohan